# Multiple choice answers for students (reading from file)

Tags: c#

How to use *split* to into *two* variables from a file?
I want to read the file until it hits the `0` then stop.
The `abcde` are multiple choice answers.
Link to code, since mobile won’t let me format code or post a pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OkER.jpg

So I have a file with the following:

```
1234 abcde
5678 abcde
9101 abcde
0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow you should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try Linq `TakeWhile`; first let's read file into `items`:

```
   var items = File
     .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt")
     .TakeWhile(line => line != "0")
     .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
     .Select(tokens => new {
        stuNum = int.Parse(tokens[0]),
        array = tokens[1],
      });
```

Then we can easily work them

```
   foreach (var item in items) {
     int stuNum = item.stuNum;
     string array = item.array;      

     ...
   }
```